# Array.select does not select an element

Tags: javascript, express

I have the following array:

```
var jobs = [
  { ID: 'grt34hggf', Title: 'tobi', Location: 'Los Angeles, CA', Description: "bla-bla-bla", DateExpiration: "FFF" },
  { ID: 'vbnhty', Title: 'n', Location: 'Los Angeles, CA', Description: "bla-bla-bla", DateExpiration: "FFF" },
  { ID: 'bnm7ii78', Title: 'bnui', Location: 'Los Angeles, CA', Description: "bla-bla-bla", DateExpiration: "FFF" }
];
```

then I try to get one element from this array. The following code does not work:

```
app.get('/job/:id', function (req, res) {
    res.render('job', {
        job: jobs.filter(function(x) { return x.ID == 'bnm7ii78'; }),
        title: "Job Descr",
        header: "descr"
    });
});
```

but the following code works:

```
app.get('/job/:id', function (req, res) {
    res.render('job', {
        job : jobs[0],
        title: "Job Descr",
        header: "descr"
    });
});
```

why?

Comment: Did you check to see what `jobs.filter(function(x) { return x.ID == 'bnm7ii78'; })` returns? Does the code you are calling expect an array?

Comment: returns "undefined" for each field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you expect an object, but `jobs.filter(...)` returns an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) of all elements that fit your condition. You can try `jobs.filter(...)[0]`.

Comment: Yes, but as I understand your filter function always will pick just one elemet, so it is ok to get it with [0].

Comment: oh, first select after filter function? Yes, you are right, thank you!